# Calculating the determinant of a matrix with a mistake

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix $5\times 5$ so $\det(A)\neq 0$ and $4A-5B=0$.
I would like to calculate:
$$\frac{1}{25}\cdot\det(4(A^t)^2B^{-1}A^{-1})$$

So I did:

$$
\frac{1}{25}\cdot\det(4(A^t)^2B^{-1}A^{-1})=\frac{1}{25}\cdot 4^5\cdot [\det(A)]^2\cdot [\det(B)]^{-1}\cdot [\det(A)]^{-1}=\\ =\frac{1024}{25}\cdot \frac{\frac{5}{4}\det(B)}{\det(B)}=\frac{256}{5}=51.2
$$

But for some reason it is not the answer. Where could be the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

$$4A = 5B$$

$$\det(4A) = \det(5B)\implies\ 4^5\det(A) = 5^5\frac{1}{\det(B^{-1})} \implies \color{blue}{\det(B^{-1}) = \frac{5^5}{4^5\det(A)}}$$

$$\det(A^T) = \det(A)$$

So, $$y=\frac{1}{25}\det(4(A^T)^2B^{-1}A^{-1}) =\frac{1}{25}4^5\det(A)^2\frac{5^5}{4^5\det(A)}\frac{1}{\det(A)}$$

> $$y = \frac{5^5}{5^2} = 125$$

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is you thinking $\det(A)=\frac54\det (B)$.  The factor should be $(5/4)^5$.